# changing d3.js reference in shiny to local

Tags: r, d3.js, shiny, plotly

I am trying to develop a Shiny app using HTML widgets, but because of our internet security, we can not access d3.js so Shiny just produces blank pages. How can I force Shiny to reference the d3R package instead of trying to log online. This only happens when I convert my code to Shiny, in a static document, I can create my plots. I want to implement sunburstR, but I tested with plotly which produced the same result.

Answer (score 2):

The newest version of [d3r](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/d3r) now has an argument `offline` which by default is `TRUE`.  This should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.